# Why is the scalar Yukawa interaction attractive, but QED attractive or repulsive?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

I just worked through the derivations of the [Yukawa interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction) for scalar and spin one particles (i.e. Peskin and Schroeder, end of chapter 4, which covers the tree-level Feynman diagram). It's very satisfying to see that the sign of the interaction is uniquely determined, but I don't feel like doing this calculation gave me much physical insight into the question of the title. There are so many minus signs to keep track of, but one of them gives us a very fundamental fact about nature.

To give an example of what an answer to this question might look like, consider the answer in classical electromagnetism. The fields generated by two positively charged particles predominantly constructively interfere throughout space. This means that the energy stored in the electromagnetic field increases as the particles are brought together, explaining the repulsive interaction. The opposite is true for a positively and a negatively charged particle brought together.

So my question is, how can we use the physics of virtual particle exchange (which store the energy of a field) to recover the fact that spin 1 bosons source attractive or repulsive interactions (depending on charges), but spin 0 only attractive? Can we understand this in terms of interference, the way we can understand it in classical electromagnetism?

Comment: That is incorrect. The scalar Yukawa interaction is always attractive. See the highlighted text here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction, or Peskin and Schroeder Eq. 4.127/top of page 123. If there were any other reasons to close the question, please clarify (I will update is slightly in a moment to clarify).